# The 'href' property had a malformed URL: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory

Tags: c#, html

I did a lot of research on this topic but I am not able to find any solution to this problem. I checked my page thoroughly but I am not able to fine "../" in my page. Need suggestions.My code on page  is like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="PassRecovery.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login_PassRecovery" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
     <style>


        input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], select, textarea {

            height: 2em;
            background:none;
            border-radius:0px;
        }
        input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="button"], .button {

            padding: 16px;
            line-height:0em;
            height:2em;
            border-radius:0px;
        }

        </style>
     <div class="container">
    <section id="main" class="container" style="padding-top:6em;">
                <header>
                    <h2>Forgot your password?</h2>
                    <p>No problem, we can send it to you.</p>
                </header>
            <div class="row" style="width:65%;margin:0 auto;min-height:331px;">
                    <div class="12u">

                        <!-- Lists -->
                            <section class="box">

  <div class="row collapse-at-2">

            <div class="requiredFieldPrompt 3u" >
                Your Email :
            </div>

            <div class="9u">
                <div class="12u">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
                <div class="12u"> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter your Email address"
                    ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></div>
                <div class="12u"> <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valEmailAddress" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Address"
                    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress"
                    Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></div>
                <br />

            </div>
 </div>

           <div class="12u" style="text-align:center;">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkGetUser" runat="server" CssClass="button"  Text="Submit" OnClick="lnkGetUser_Click"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CssClass="button"  href="Login.aspx" Text="Back" CausesValidation="false"
                    OnClick="lnkCancel_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
           </div>


    <div class="12u" style="text-align: center;">
        <h4>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label></h4>
    </div>


            <div class="12u" style="text-align:center;">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkContinue" runat="server"  href="Login.aspx" Text="Sign in to your account" 
                    CausesValidation="false" onclick="lnkContinue_Click"></asp:LinkButton>

            </div>

                                </section>

                    </div>
                </div>

   </section>
         </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer. Problem was with the master page. my masterpage was in the main directory and I was using ../ on it. Thx All. :)